# How do I convert the time property in MixPanel?

Tags: python, mixpanel

I'm using MixPanel and trying to convert the ['property']['time'] field that I get when I'm reviewing events. I thought it was a UTC time, and this is how I'm trying to convert the value back to my local timezone.

```
from dateutil import tz

from_zone = tz.tzutc()
to_zone = tz.tzlocal()

def convert_from_mix_time(mix_time):
    utc_date = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(mix_time))
    utc_date = utc_date.replace(tzinfo=from_zone)
    local_date = utc_date.astimezone(to_zone)
    return local_date
```

Taking the MixPanel time 1394199886 (this should be 4:44 PM EST), the UTC time is 2014-03-07 08:44:46+00:00 and the converted time is 2014-03-07 03:44:46 (definitely not the right time). Anyone know how to do the conversion?

Answer (score 0):

I don't get that timestamp to be 4:44 PM EST, but I could recommend `utcfromtimestamp()` if you want your code to be a bit simpler.

```
    dt = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(ts)
```

Comment: Thanks, that does clean it up a little.

Answer (score 0):

You need to normalize the datetime object:

```
def convert_mix_time(mix_time):
  utc_date = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(int(mix_time))
  utc_date = utc_date.replace(tzinfo=from_zone)
  local_date = utc_date.astimezone(to_zone)
  return from_zone.normalize(local_date)
```

Comment: Thanks, but that gives me basically the same answer that I had before. I strongly suspect that the mixpanel timestamps are PST times and not UTC. That's the only way I can get the correct EST time.

Answer (score 0):

The timzeone of the data is defined per project. Click on the geat icon at the bottom right of Mixpanel's Web UI. It'll open a window. In the Data management section there's a Timezone field. Set it to UTC. that's the timezone Mixpanel will record the data coming in. Note that it won't affect past data. After that you can convert the timezone like you did.